# Pico Pi Python - Onewire temperature sensor

Tags: python

I am trying to get temperature sensor to work on pico pi, using PIN 16. I got DS18X20 and onewire library from GitHub. I'm trying to get temperature reading but it shows an error.

I tried running this code:

```
import time
import machine
import ds18x20
import onewire

# the device is on GPIO12
dat = machine.Pin(22)

# create the onewire object
on = onewire.OneWire(dat)
ds = ds18x20.DS18X20(on)

# scan for devices on the bus
roms = ds.scan()
print('found devices:', roms)

# loop 10 times and print all temperatures
for i in range(10):
    print('temperatures:', end=' ')
    ds.convert_temp()
    time.sleep_ms(750)
    for rom in roms:
        print(ds.read_temp(rom), end=' ')
    print()
```

This is DS18X0 library:

```
"""
DS18x20 temperature sensor driver for MicroPython.
This driver uses the OneWire driver to control DS18S20 and DS18B20
temperature sensors.  It supports multiple devices on the same 1-wire bus.
The following example assumes the ground of your DS18x20 is connected to
Y11, vcc is connected to Y9 and the data pin is connected to Y10.
>>> from pyb import Pin
>>> gnd = Pin('Y11', Pin.OUT_PP)
>>> gnd.low()
>>> vcc = Pin('Y9', Pin.OUT_PP)
>>> vcc.high()
>>> from ds18x20 import DS18X20
>>> d = DS18X20(Pin('Y10'))
Call read_temps to read all sensors:
>>> result = d.read_temps()
>>> print(result)
[20.875, 20.8125]
Call read_temp to read the temperature of a specific sensor:
>>> result = d.read_temp(d.roms[0])
>>> print(result)
20.25
If only one DS18x20 is attached to the bus, then you don't need to 
pass a ROM to read_temp:
>>> result = d.read_temp()
>>> print(result)
20.25
"""

from onewire import OneWire

class DS18X20(object):
    def __init__(self, pin):
        self.ow = OneWire(pin)
        # Scan the 1-wire devices, but only keep those which have the
        # correct # first byte in their rom for a DS18x20 device.
        self.roms = [rom for rom in self.ow.scan() if rom[0] == 0x10 or rom[0] == 0x28]

    def read_temp(self, rom=None):
        """
        Read and return the temperature of one DS18x20 device.
        Pass the 8-byte bytes object with the ROM of the specific device you want to read.
        If only one DS18x20 device is attached to the bus you may omit the rom parameter.
        """
        rom = rom or self.roms[0]
        ow = self.ow
        ow.reset()
        ow.select_rom(rom)
        ow.write_byte(0x44)  # Convert Temp
        while True:
            if ow.read_bit():
                break
        ow.reset()
        ow.select_rom(rom)
        ow.write_byte(0xbe)  # Read scratch
        data = ow.read_bytes(9)
        return self.convert_temp(rom[0], data)

    def read_temps(self):
        """
        Read and return the temperatures of all attached DS18x20 devices.
        """
        temps = []
        for rom in self.roms:
            temps.append(self.read_temp(rom))
        return temps

    def convert_temp(self, rom0, data):
        """
        Convert the raw temperature data into degrees celsius and return as a float.
        """
        temp_lsb = data[0]
        temp_msb = data[1]
        if rom0 == 0x10:
            if temp_msb != 0:
                # convert negative number
                temp_read = temp_lsb >> 1 | 0x80  # truncate bit 0 by shifting, fill high bit with 1.
                temp_read = -((~temp_read + 1) & 0xff) # now convert from two's complement
            else:
                temp_read = temp_lsb >> 1  # truncate bit 0 by shifting
            count_remain = data[6]
            count_per_c = data[7]
            temp = temp_read - 0.25 + (count_per_c - count_remain) / count_per_c
            return temp
        elif rom0 == 0x28:
            return (temp_msb << 8 | temp_lsb) / 16
        else:
            assert False
```

This is onewire library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright (c) 2019, Pycom Limited.
#
# This software is licensed under the GNU GPL version 3 or any
# later version, with permitted additional terms. For more information
# see the Pycom Licence v1.0 document supplied with this file, or
# available at https://www.pycom.io/opensource/licensing
#

"""
OneWire library for MicroPython
"""

import time
import machine

class OneWire:
    CMD_SEARCHROM = const(0xf0)
    CMD_READROM = const(0x33)
    CMD_MATCHROM = const(0x55)
    CMD_SKIPROM = const(0xcc)
    
    
    
    
        
    def __init__(self, pin):
        self.pin = pin
        self.pin.init(pin.OPEN_DRAIN, pin.PULL_UP)
        print("init")

    def init(self, pin):
        self.pin = pin
        self.pin.init(pin.OPEN_DRAIN, pin.PULL_UP)
        print("init")

    def reset(self):
        """
        Perform the onewire reset function.
        Returns True if a device asserted a presence pulse, False otherwise.
        """
        sleep_us = time.sleep_us
        disable_irq = machine.disable_irq
        enable_irq = machine.enable_irq
        pin = self.pin

        pin(0)
        sleep_us(480)
        i = disable_irq()
        pin(1)
        sleep_us(60)
        status = not pin()
        enable_irq(i)
        sleep_us(420)
        return status

    def read_bit(self):
        sleep_us = time.sleep_us
        enable_irq = machine.enable_irq
        pin = self.pin

        pin(1) # half of the devices don't match CRC without this line
        i = machine.disable_irq()
        pin(0)
        sleep_us(1)
        pin(1)
        sleep_us(1)
        value = pin()
        enable_irq(i)
        sleep_us(40)
        return value

    def read_byte(self):
        value = 0
        for i in range(8):
            value |= self.read_bit() << i
        return value

    def read_bytes(self, count):
        buf = bytearray(count)
        for i in range(count):
            buf[i] = self.read_byte()
        return buf

    def write_bit(self, value):
        sleep_us = time.sleep_us
        pin = self.pin

        i = machine.disable_irq()
        pin(0)
        sleep_us(1)
        pin(value)
        sleep_us(60)
        pin(1)
        sleep_us(1)
        machine.enable_irq(i)

    def write_byte(self, value):
        for i in range(8):
            self.write_bit(value & 1)
            value >>= 1

    def write_bytes(self, buf):
        for b in buf:
            self.write_byte(b)

    def select_rom(self, rom):
        """
        Select a specific device to talk to. Pass in rom as a bytearray (8 bytes).
        """
        self.reset()
        self.write_byte(CMD_MATCHROM)
        self.write_bytes(rom)

    def crc8(self, data):
        """
        Compute CRC
        """
        crc = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            byte = data[i]
            for b in range(8):
                fb_bit = (crc ^ byte) & 0x01
                if fb_bit == 0x01:
                    crc = crc ^ 0x18
                crc = (crc >> 1) & 0x7f
                if fb_bit == 0x01:
                    crc = crc | 0x80
                byte = byte >> 1
        return crc

    def scan(self):
        """
        Return a list of ROMs for all attached devices.
        Each ROM is returned as a bytes object of 8 bytes.
        """
        devices = []
        diff = 65
        rom = False
        for i in range(0xff):
            rom, diff = self._search_rom(rom, diff)
            if rom:
                devices += [rom]
            if diff == 0:
                break
        return devices

    def _search_rom(self, l_rom, diff):
        if not self.reset():
            return None, 0
        self.write_byte(CMD_SEARCHROM)
        if not l_rom:
            l_rom = bytearray(8)
        rom = bytearray(8)
        next_diff = 0
        i = 64
        for byte in range(8):
            r_b = 0
            for bit in range(8):
                b = self.read_bit()
                if self.read_bit():
                    if b: # there are no devices or there is an error on the bus
                        return None, 0
                else:
                    if not b: # collision, two devices with different bit meaning
                        if diff > i or ((l_rom[byte] & (1 << bit)) and diff != i):
                            b = 1
                            next_diff = i
                self.write_bit(b)
                if b:
                    r_b |= 1 << bit
                i -= 1
            rom[byte] = r_b
        return rom, next_diff

class DS18X20(object):
    def __init__(self, onewire):
        self.ow = onewire
        self.roms = [rom for rom in self.ow.scan() if rom[0] == 0x10 or rom[0] == 0x28]
        self.fp = True
        try:
            1/1
        except TypeError:
            self.fp = False # floatingpoint not supported

    def isbusy(self):
        """
        Checks wether one of the DS18x20 devices on the bus is busy
        performing a temperature convertion
        """
        return not self.ow.read_bit()

    def start_conversion(self, rom=None):
        """
        Start the temp conversion on one DS18x20 device.
        Pass the 8-byte bytes object with the ROM of the specific device you want to read.
        If only one DS18x20 device is attached to the bus you may omit the rom parameter.
        """
        if (rom==None) and (len(self.roms)>0):
            rom=self.roms[0]
        if rom!=None:    
            rom = rom or self.roms[0]
            ow = self.ow
            ow.reset()
            ow.select_rom(rom)
            ow.write_byte(0x44)  # Convert Temp

    def read_temp_async(self, rom=None):
        """
        Read the temperature of one DS18x20 device if the convertion is complete,
        otherwise return None.
        """
        if self.isbusy():
            return None
        if (rom==None) and (len(self.roms)>0):
            rom=self.roms[0]
        if rom==None:     
            return None
        else:
            ow = self.ow
            ow.reset()
            ow.select_rom(rom)
            ow.write_byte(0xbe)  # Read scratch
            data = ow.read_bytes(9)
            return self.convert_temp(rom[0], data)

    def convert_temp(self, rom0, data):
        """
        Convert the raw temperature data into degrees celsius and return as a fixed point with 2 decimal places.
        """
        temp_lsb = data[0]
        temp_msb = data[1]
        if rom0 == 0x10:
            if temp_msb != 0:
                # convert negative number
                temp_read = temp_lsb >> 1 | 0x80  # truncate bit 0 by shifting, fill high bit with 1.
                temp_read = -((~temp_read + 1) & 0xff) # now convert from two's complement
            else:
                temp_read = temp_lsb >> 1  # truncate bit 0 by shifting
            count_remain = data[6]
            count_per_c = data[7]
            if self.fp:
                return temp_read - 25 + (count_per_c - count_remain) / count_per_c
            else:
                return 100 * temp_read - 25 + (count_per_c - count_remain) // count_per_c
        elif rom0 == 0x28:
            temp = None
            if self.fp:
                temp = (temp_msb << 8 | temp_lsb) / 16
            else:
                temp = (temp_msb << 8 | temp_lsb) * 100 // 16
            if (temp_msb & 0xf8) == 0xf8: # for negative temperature
                temp -= 0x1000
            return temp
        else:
            assert False
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
  File "ds18x20.py", line 33, in __init__
  File "onewire.py", line 30, in __init__
AttributeError: 'OneWire' object has no attribute 'OPEN_DRAIN'
>>>
```

I've tried multiple ways to resolve this and watched a bunch of videos on youtube, but not sure what causes this issue.

Comment: The `DS18X20` class creates its own `OneWire` object, and requires a `Pin` to be passed as a parameter.  You're passing your own `OneWire` instead.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Changed the line ds = ds18x20.DS18X20(on) to ds = ds18x20.DS18X20(dat). Now I don't get an error, but I get  >>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
init
init

Comment: Change the code to the following:                                                                                                                       import time
from machine import Pin, ADC
from ds18x20 import DS18X20
from onewire import OneWire

#DS18B20 data line connected to pin 16
ow = OneWire(Pin(16))
print ("success")
print (ow.readbyte())
print ("success2")
temp = DS18X20(ow)

Comment: I now get the following    :>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
success
255   It then stops working or responding